# Replace custom tag inside a string with value from database

Tags: php, regex

what I need to do is to parse a string similar to this:

> {a}3{/a}*{b}4{/b}

or this

> {a}3{/a}/{b}2{/b}*100

I need to substitute in that string those values within the tags with real values from the database, the first example:

`SELECT value FROM table WHERE id = 3;`

`SELECT value FROM table WHERE id = 4;`

This function:

`preg_replace_callback('/(?>{([^}]+)})(.*)?{\/\1}/sim', 'find_tags_callback', $string);`

Actually returns the ids contained in the string, the problem is that I'm stuck there. In pseudo code I  would need to:

Extract the first id from the string.

Run my query.

Substitute that id with the correct value.

[Do the same for all tags]

Finish having back the initial string with the correct value inside.
The first might be

> 10*3

the second

> 40/90*100

Any idea how to do this, I'm completely stuck.

Thanks

Comment: Query the database once, and build an array mapping all the tags to their values. Then `find_tags_callback` looks up the tag and returns the value.

Comment: How do you rebuild the string? find_tags_callback just returns that matched value, how about the rest? How do I pass inside the function the array from the db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a database query to get all the values, and put them into an array keyed off the IDs. In the code below, I assume the array is named `$tags`.

```
$new_string = preg_replace_callback('/\{([^}]+)\}(.+?)\{/\1\}/sim', 
    function ($match) use ($tags) {
        return $tags[$match[2]];
    }, $string);
```

The `use ($tags)` declaration allows the function to reference the external variable `$tags`.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't knew about use().

Comment: Do you know about `global`? You could also use that.